# Latency in TCP communication via WiFi between Android tablet and laptop

Tags: android, sockets, networking, tcp, c++-cli

In my setup, I use a PC (laptop) with Win7 that creates a hosted network (WiFi). I program it in C++/CLI (.net). On the other side, I have a tablet with Android (ICS). The tablet is the *server* and the PC is the *client*. I chose TCP for accuracy, I exchange commands, I don't want to loose packets.

On the tablet side, I use a `ServerSocket` that waits for communication with the method `accept()`. Then it returns a `Socket`, etc.

On the PC side, I use a `Socket` then I connect it to the tablet using `connect()`. After it is done, I `send()` bytes to the tablet that get them through its `InputBuffer`... The it returns bytes through its `OutputBuffer` and they are retrieved in the PC by calling `receive()`.

The problem is that sometimes it takes few seconds for a send/receive cycle, other times it takes few tens of milliseconds. So here are my questions:

1. Is it a normal behavior that we can expect for such communications?
2. Can we fine tune this behavior by setting, say, buffer sizes or other things?
3. What is the longest step: connecting or transferring data?

I would appreciate if someone could give me some clues. I'm pretty new in network programmation and sometime "*I'm loosing my latin!*" (well... a french expression!)

---

**Code examples:** (skipping trivial code and comments...)

**PC side** (C++/CLI)

```
Socket^ lpSocket = gcnew Socket( SocketType::Stream, ProtocolType::Tcp );

lpSocket->Connect( Addr, Port ); // PROBLEMS HERE

SocketError err;
array<Byte>^ lOutBuffer = Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes( "Here's a sentence.\r\n" );
lpSocket->Send( lOutBuffer, 0, lOutBuffer->Length, SocketFlags::None, err );
array<Byte>^ lInBuffer = gcnew array<Byte>( 1024 );
int N = lpSocket->Receive( lInBuffer, 0, lInBuffer->Length, SocketFlags::None, err );
String^ lpOutString = Encoding::UTF8->getString( lInBuffer, 0, N );
```

**Tablet side** (Android ICS) The code is a little more complicated due to threading. I will skip the mandatory try/catch...

```
// ... We are in a background thread
ServerSocket mSS = new ServerSocket();
mSS.bind( new InetSocketAddress( mPort ) );
mSS.setReuseAddress( true );

Socket lCS = mSS.accept();
lCS.setSoTimeout( 1 );
lCS.setTcpNoDelay( true );

BufferedInputStream lIn = new BufferedInputStream( lCS.getInputStream() );
PrintStream lPS = new PrintStream( lCS.getOutputStream() );
byte[] lBuf = new byte[1024];
String lInStr="";

while ( true )
{
    try
    {
        if ( lInStr.endsWith( "\r\n" ) ) { break; }

        int N;
        if ((N=lIn.read( lBuf,0,1024))!=-1) { lInStr += new String( lBuf, 0, N, "UTF-8" );}
        else { break; }
    }
    catch ( SocketTimeoutException e )
    { /* Can occur because timeout is set to 1ms */ }
}

lOut.print( lInStr ); // Just echo input to output
lOut.close();
lCS.close();

mSS.close();
```

So, it is a simple app where I can accept one connection. Once it is accepted, I process it, then I close the sockets and that's it.

The problems occur (it seems) in the PC side with `connect()`. I often get error **Timeout** or **ConnectionRefused**. If I redo the `connect()` in a loop, I obtain a connection. *But even when there is no timeout, the connection can take few seconds to establish.*

Comment: @HAL9000 See my edit, I added code for both sides.

Comment: How do you know `accept()` has not been issued after the client called `connect()`? In addition, aren't you supposed to call `listen()` before `accept()`?

Comment: You connect, echo one one line of text in the server and then close the socket, ie disconnect?  Is that what you intended because, if so, you can look forward to very poor, latency-ridden performance, especially over wireless networks.  Connect/disconnect protocols are bad over low-latency links because of the 3/4-way TCP connect/disconnect sequences.  Over wireless, they are just dire.

Comment: @Asblarf 1) I know that `accept()` didn't return immediately after `connect()` because I follow it in debug. 2) There is no such method called `listen()` in the class `Android.net.ServerSocket`.

Comment: @MartinJames My intent is to send a command from the PC then get the answer from the tablet. There is no link between each command issued and they can be separated by 10ms or by 10 hours... I tough that I had to connect, issue the command by send/receive, then disconnect. It seems that the `connect()/accept()` is the bottleneck? The problem is that I developed the app on a computer where this process was fast and now I'm debugging it on a computer where this process is slow. I really do not know why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WiFi in the tablet I was working with is bugged. I tried with a phone and other tablets and it works quite fine.

I don't know actually if it is a bug with the version of Android (4.0.3) or if it is a hardware issue because I could not test two different tablets having the same Android.

Anyway...

I appreciate the help you gave me when saying that the connection delay looked too long. This is what sent me to the right path to the solution!